# Fortran Error # 6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform

Tags: arrays, fortran

I encountered this error message while compiling one of my Fortran codes. I found a few similar posts regarding the same error, but none of the situations in those posts apply to my case. I would appreciate any answer or help offered here. Thanks in advance!

(The code is really long, so I only cut out those sentences that are relevant.)

===================================================

```
DIMENSION A(20), COORDS(3)
REAL  B, C, X, Y, Z

B = 1.0

X = COORDS(1)
Y = COORDS(2)
Z = COORDS(3)

DO I = 1,3
  A(I) = COORDS(I)
END DO

C = SQRT ( X**2.0 + Y**2.0 ) + B
```

===================================================

**The error message points to the last line:**
error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform. [`C`]

If I comment out `+ B`, then no error occurs.

I just don't get it. The elements of the array `COORDS` are passed on to scalar variables `X, Y, Z`. How come they and `B` (or `C`) are not conformable?

I know there must be something I don't quite understand about Fortran array. Please point out my mistake if you catch any.

Thanks a lot!

Justin

Answer (score 3):

Is there a `dimension` statement elsewhere in the code for any of these variables?   The error message seems to point to `C`; that commenting out `+B` eliminates the error seems to more solidly point to `B`.

This is why I like to have all characteristics of a variable declared on a single line.
e.g.,

```
real, dimension (20) :: a
```

instead of:

```
dimension A(20)
real A
```

Comment: In more detail - the compiler believes that B is an array but C, X and Y are not. Adding +B to the expression turns the entire expression into an array, but if C is not also an array of the same shape, that's an error. In cases such as this, it is more helpful to provide a small but complete example that shows the problem, rather than an excerpt or paraphrase, as these often leave out critical details.